# How to bind a IFormatProvider implementation to a specific culture?

Tags: c#, formatting

I know in order to provide a format provider I need to implement `IFormatProvider` interface.

However, what about if I want to bind it to a specific culture?
How to do that?

Comment: I don't understand. `CultureInfo` _already_ [implements](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,50) `IFormatProvider`. You mean like `new CulturInfo("en-US")` or `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")`? But those are _still_ returns `CultureInfo` type. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I've realized that for example, if I want to provide a Number format provider in order to show it as a file size, I could want to change its implementation in order to show "kilo bytes" instead of "kb"...

Comment: Then it would be better to see your example first.

Comment: For example take a look on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/atifaziz/9109568#file-bytesizeformatprovider-cs). If the application is running under an ES-es culture I could show "10Kb". By other hand, under another culture, the format provider could show "10 KB".

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
someText.ToString(ci)
```

use `CultureInfo`.

Comment: This is not what OP asking either.

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");;